# Testing if \BODY is empty in Environ

Tags: environments

I would like to test whether the string in `\expandafter\long\expandafter\xdef\csname\currfilebase\Introduction` is empty so that the section is not displayed. This environment `introduction` is defined in a file in `P/Fourier.tex`. Of course, what I did here does not work. I have tried many if the `\if...` commands from `etoolbox` but all seem to not work. (tried here).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{filehook}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\def\Introduction{Introduction}


\NewEnviron{introduction}{%
      \expandafter\long\expandafter\xdef\csname\currfilebase\Introduction \endcsname{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}%
}%


\AtEndOfIncludes{%
  \ifcurrfiledir{P/}{%
    \ifdefequal{\csname\currfilebase\Introduction\endcsname}{ }{True}{False}%
    \section{Introduction}%
    \csname \currfilebase \Introduction \endcsname}%
}%

\begin{document}    
\include{P/Fourier}
\end{document}
```

And `P/Fourier.tex` contains

```
\begin{introduction}
Test
\end{introduction}
```

I have a couple of those environment and I wish that they are not shown in the final pdf. So I have something like this if the file is empty:
[image: Example]

**Edit:** Fixed the missing `}` and removed an irrelevant line.

**Edit #2:** I have changed this to the following code (with `etoolbox`):

```
\ifcsvoid{\currfilebase\Introduction}{}{%
      \section{Introduction}%
      \csname\currfilebase\Introduction\endcsname}%
```

This seems to work! Is this a good way of doing things? Thanks guys, now I have also learned `\show` which helped a lot!

**Edit #3:** Since I am already using `etoolbox` I can do use all others commands as well anyway, so

```
\newcommand{\makesection}[1]{\ifcsvoid{\currfilebase#1}{}%
  {%
    \section{#1}%
    \csuse{\currfilebase#1}%
  }%
}%
```

(I have done the same in the rest too)

Comment: could you remove the `\include{P/Fourier}` in your code and replace it by a small section of document that shows the problem? as it is, we can't run it.

Comment: I think `\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\csname\currfilebase\Introduction\endcsname\relax TRUE \else FALSE \fi` could do the trick. But I can't test it right now.

Comment: My apologies,I manually shortened the file. Will fix it in a couple a hours when I can access a real computer.

Comment: Should be working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is already quite nice, what you did there, Jonas, and would probably have justified a self-answer. I only added some small changes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{filehook}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\introductionname{Introduction}
\def\methodsname{Methods}
\def\ideasname{Ideas}

\newcommand\defenviron[1]{\NewEnviron{#1}{\expandafter\long\expandafter\xdef\csname\currfilebase #1\endcsname{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}}}

\defenviron{introduction}
\defenviron{methods}
\defenviron{ideas}

\newcommand\makesection[1]{\ifcsvoid{\currfilebase #1}{}%
  {%
    \section{\csname#1name\endcsname}%
    \csuse{\currfilebase #1}%
  }%
}%

\AtEndOfIncludes{%
    \ifcurrfiledir{P/}{%
        \makesection{introduction}%
        \makesection{methods}%
        \makesection{ideas}%
        }{}%
}%

\begin{document}    
    \include{P/Fourier}
\end{document}
```

First of all I put those environment definitions in their own command `\defenviron` for convenience. Second I changed the naming scheme just a litte. Then I also added the missing false case for `\ifcurrfiledir`. But that's about it.

You could probably also loop over the environments in those two places, if the code is really this uniform.

Comment: Great. This is what I have changed in the end! I also added the `capitalize` of the `stringstring` package. One issue was that I would like to mix the commands `makesection` and `defenviron`. The problem is of course that after multiple inputs I will get errors! Perhaps I need to have a test that checks if this is already done. After that I can iterate over an `etoolbox` list. That worked but gave errors about something not being found while it was typeset. In any case, that would be a new question!

Answer (score 4):

You have a missing `}` in your code, if I fix that and then arrange the thing so it works in my directory setup and add

```
\expandafter\show\csname\currfilebase\Introduction\endcsname
```

Just before your test then I get

> \env2-aIntroduction=\relax.

If there is no introduction at all and

```
> \env2-aIntroduction=\long macro:
->\ignorespaces .
```

If there is an empty introduction.

So you need to test if it has a definition just consisting of `\ignorespaces` (or don't add `\ignorespaces` unconditionally in your definition.

I then stopped at

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\scr@ds@tocentry ->\convertchar
```

which is I assume an unrelated local macro? so am not including a working version of the document as I would normally do.

Comment: You forgot to mention when the second case occurs. Also citation and code markup seem not consistent.

Comment: @canaaerus I didn't look at what else the doc was doing, I gave up after explaining the main csname test question as there were other errors. If you have a more complete fix feel free to post a full answer and I'll probably delete this one.

Comment: @David: Thanks. I think I have fixed it now. So I remove `\ignorespaces` and fix it elsewhere? What test would work?